# Why does this JavaScript function behave so strangely?

Tags: javascript

Observe:

```
function myFunc(arg1, arg2) {
  if (arguments.length < 2) { // Only one argument received
    arg1 = "Default"; // Set arg1 to some default value
    arg2 = arguments[0]; // Use the first argument passed for arg2
  }
  return [arg1, arg2];
}

myFunc("Hello", "World"); //=> ["Hello", "World"]

// So far, so good. Now let's try one that uses the default value for arg1:

myFunc("World"); //=> ["Default", "Default"]
```

What the heck, JavaScript? What's going on here? Why does JavaScript behave this way?

Comment: @MIIB It's a special variable in JavaScript which is basically an object containg all arguments passed to a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: so why dont you just put arg1 to arg2 and then change arg1 to default. Then what hapends? :P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are overwriting your first argument before using its value:

```
arg1 = "Default"; // Set arg1 to some default value
arg2 = arguments[0]; // Use the first argument passed for arg2
```

So the value of `arg2` is set to the value "Default" rather than the original value.

Comment: Noting that any named arguments given values are getters/setters for their respective entry in `arguments`, which is why setting `arg1` affects `arguments[0]`.

Comment: Correct, Jonathan, thank you. OP, your question states you want an explanation of the behavior. Is the explanation above sufficient or do you want a workaround as well?

Comment: Wow, that's confusing behavior. Thanks, that explains the "what" part. And it looks like @Jacob Krall sort of explained the "why" in his answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Try switching the logic in your if statement:

```
function myFunc(arg1, arg2) {
  if (arguments.length < 2) { // Only one argument received
    arg2 = arguments[0]; // Use the first argument passed for arg2
    arg1 = "Default"; // Set arg1 to some default value
  }
  return [arg1, arg2];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, 30 seconds *can* matter that much!

Answer (score 3):

It's part of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6):

> For non-strict mode functions the array index (defined in 15.4) named
>   data properties of an arguments object whose numeric name values are
>   less than the number of formal parameters of the corresponding
>   function object initially share their values with the corresponding
>   argument bindings in the function’s execution context. **This means that
>   changing the property changes the corresponding value of the argument
>   binding and vice-versa.** This correspondence is broken if such a
>   property is deleted and then redefined or if the property is changed
>   into an accessor property. For strict mode functions, the values of
>   the arguments object’s properties are simply a copy of the arguments
>   passed to the function and there is no dynamic linkage between the
>   property values and the formal parameter values.

Note that your function works as expected if you `"use strict";`.

Comment: Ah, the spec. Thanks, that's perfect. I wonder what was going through the language designer's heads when they decided that would be reasonable behavior. O.o

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it was for ease of implementation. That is: named arguments are implemented as indexes into `arguments[]`

Comment: This is the correct answer here, using strict mode.